# Track Vert.X eventbus disconnection

Tags: java, vert.x, event-bus, vertx-verticle

I would like to know if is possible with Vert.X and its event bus (and several servers on the same eventbus), to be alert if a disconnection (a connection lost) with a remote server.

For example, we have several client(slave) servers and one master, we want to be informed when the connection between client/master.

In order to register a special event at the disconnection.

There exists a type of handler/callback which can be automatically notified by Vert.X ?

thank a lot and best regards